# Android 6.0 runtime permission + intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, android-permissions, intentfilter

I need to access storage in my intent filter to grab a pdf file or image in Android 6.0 application.

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionOpenDocument, Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataMimeType = "application/pdf")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionOpenDocument, Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataMimeType = "image/jpeg")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionOpenDocument, Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataMimeType = "image/png")]
```

However, it requires from user grant Storage permission for app.

The question is there any proper POC for such case, that I can block intent, display alert and after that finish my intent basing on grant/revoke of permission?

Presently I assume I can only display some toast that there is no permission and gently ask user to go into app and enable permission manually (from some custom app settings, or whatever).

Comment: Kindly be specific for what you need ?? little bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

```
   private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;

     void checkPremission() {
            //Desired permission you want
            final String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
                // if in fragment use getActivity()

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityName.this, permission)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                // you have permission go ahead

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                    final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                    final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                            && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                    if (isGranted) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                    }else{
                        // you dont have permission show toast
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, but maybe I forgot to mention it in the question, but I tagged it - that I was looking for an answer for Xamarin technology.

Time passed, but that time ago, eventually, we found solution. It is more-less such piece of code:

```
        private bool HandlAndroidRuntimePermissions(Intent intent)
        {
            const int toastTimeout = 5;
            const string permissionName = "File Drop";

            try
            {
                PermissionStatus status;
                using (var checkPermissionStatusAsync = CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage))
                {
                    status = checkPermissionStatusAsync.Result;
                }

                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    using (var shouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync = CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
                    {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync.Result)
                        {
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(
                                string.Format(Core.Resources.Resource.DocumentPickerModalViewModel_AndroidPermissionWrapper_RequestPermissionRationale, Permission.Storage, permissionName),
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds (toastTimeout));
                        }
                    }

                    using (var requestPermissionsAsync = CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage))
                    {
                        requestPermissionsAsync.ContinueWith(task =>
                        {
                            var permissionStatuses = task.Result;
                            status = permissionStatuses[Permission.Storage];
                            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                            {
                                CopyDocumentFromDeviceToMyLibrary(intent);
                            }
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(string.Format(Core.Resources.Resource.DocumentPickerModalViewModel_AndroidPermissionWrapper_PermissionNotGrant, Permission.Storage, permissionName),
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds (toastTimeout));
                        });
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(string.Format(Core.Resources.Resource.DocumentPickerModalViewModel_AndroidPermissionWrapper_ErrorOccured, Permission.Storage),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds (toastTimeout));
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```